# Build Image for emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I have Android source code. I make some changes in framework code. Now I want to see my changes in emulator. Can anybody tell me how I can make Image for emulator...???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build the whole source using

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch
make -j4 # change 4 to the number of cores+1
```

and then make a SD card image, detailed instructions for example here: http://nilvec.com/testing-an-android-image-built-from-source/